# What is the difference between KDE and GNOME , for embedded development host decision

Tags: gnome, kde

What are all the differences between the KDE and GNOME projects?

This is because, I want to select one (either KDE/GNOME) as my host OS for my embedded development project.

I would like to get all details(both code level and GUI level) like C(GTK for GNOME) and C++(QT for KDE)

Also , why these kind of classification?

Which one is more efficient or stable in one developers perspective?

__Kanu

Comment: Without more context for your question, and answer that is both comprehensive and useful is impossible.  Running the diff command on the source trees of the two projects would give you 'all the differences' in some sense, but the output would be completely useless.  Also, your accept-rate is very low, so people are less likely to bother to help you find useful information.

Comment: @Renjith G, it looks like you need to start clarify your questions, do some upvoting, and then accept some answers....

Comment: Sorry all...i have accepted all the valid answers from you guys.

Comment: Why do you care about code level details for KDE or GNOME just for using it? What do you meant by "why these kind of classification"?

Comment: @appu: Please read the subject and reply

Comment: @Renjith...Still the question doesn't make sense. Embedded development has no relation with KDE or GNOME. They are just desktop environments providing rich graphical user interface.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference is that KDE is C++ with Qt, while Gnome is C based on top of GTK.

Then you have the windowmanager that has a different philosophy on what to show the user.

And then you have the applications that that is just different...

---

Update: They are both good nice and stable (if you select the right versions).
They can do approximately the same but in different ways, so it is hard to compare.

My personal view is that Qt is a nice framework to write software with, 
but I also know that there is a lot of guys that would say exactly the same for gtk.

Since this is the topic for a classic flamewar, [there is a lot written all over the internet on this topic](http://www.google.com/search?q=kde+vs+gnome).

---

But when it comes to embedded the answer is simpler, since Nokia (the phone maker) is now the owner of Trolltech (the maker of Qt), they have pushed Qt to become a valid choice for embedded. And there is now a version of Qt called "[Qt for embedded linux](http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/qt-for-embedded-linux/)". 
And they created a new distribution with Intel and the Linux Foundation called [MeeGo](http://meego.com/).
So Qt has a lot of support in the Embedded realm, and it has a quite good [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/) so it is easy to get started.

A example that you can look at/use is [MeeGo on the BeagleBoard](http://wiki.meego.com/ARM/Meego_on_Beagleboard_from_scratch).

Comment: please explain with their expansions and reasons..